# Fail to save a complex JSON' structure in DynamicEmbeddedDocument (Mongoengine, Flask)

Tags: python, json, mongodb, flask, mongoengine

I have a problem trying to save a JSON request into a DynamicDocument in MongoDB using mongoengine.

Here is my Document:

```
class documentSource(DynamicEmbeddedDocument):
    name = StringField()

class documentParent(Document):
    name = StringField(max_length=120)
    source = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField('documentSource'))
```

This is my request POST object:

```
{
      "name": "Test", 
      "source": [{
          "name": "my first source"
          "metadata": {
            "name": "testing",
            "products": [
                {"name":"my product", "price":123}
            ]
          }
       },{
          "name": "my second source"
          "metadata": {
            "name": "Test",
            "profile": "foo"
          }
       }
      ]
    }
```

Here's my Flask post method:

```
def post(self):
        myObj = documentParent(
            name=self.data['name'],
            description=self.data['description'],
        )

        sourceList = []
        for i in self.data['source']:
            content = documentSource(**i)
            sourceList.append(content)
        myObj.source = sourceList
        myObj.save()
```

But the problem is:

If I send this JSON doesn't work:

```
{
      "name": "Test", 
      "source": [{
          "name": "my first source"
          "metadata": {
            "name": "testing",
            "products": [
                {"name":"my product", "price":123}
            ]
          }
       },{
          "name": "my second source"
          "metadata": {
            "name": "Test",
            "profile": "foo",
            "foo" : {
              "foo1": "var1"
            }
          }
       }
      ]
    }
```

But with this object works:

```
{
      "name": "Test", 
      "source": [{
          "name": "my first source"
          "metadata": {
            "name": "testing",
            "products": [
                "my product"
            ]
          }
       },{
          "name": "my second source"
          "metadata": {
            "name": "Test",
            "profile": "foo"
          }
       }
      ]
    }
```

The same problem with list of list:

```
"image":
  {"available_sizes":
    [[[150,
       19],
      "assets/images/150x150.png"],
     [[250,
       31],
      "assets/images/250x250.png"],
     [[450,
       57],
      "assets/images/450x450.png"]]
```

I think with complex json' structures mongoengine's parser doesn't work. I don't know how to figure out this problem because I can't control the source information, the big picture is take a JSON Object from a source (eg: Website crawlers) and save it (as it comes) into my DynamicDocument.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing commas after "my first source" and "my second source". Your JSON is not valid.

Valid:

```
{
"name": "Test",
"source": [{
    "name": "my first source",
    "metadata": {
        "name": "testing",
        "products": [{
            "name": "my product",
            "price": 123
        }]
    }
}, {
    "name": "my second source",
    "metadata": {
        "name": "Test",
        "profile": "foo",
        "foo": {
            "foo1": "var1"
        }
    }
}]
```

}

Nifty tool for validating your JSON:

https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: No sorry, it was an error to copy&paste to this question, in fact I use postman to make request, and postman have a validator.

Comment: The answer is correct. Your JSON is invalid. Accept it and post a different question...